# AppSync @connection not making two-way connection

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I'm using graphql through AWS AppSync. Given my models below I would expect when I successfully `createClassroom` with `createClassroomInput` that the teacherClassrooms would have a new Classroom associated to it and that the newly created Classroom would have a teacher associated to it.

The outcome, however, is that `Classroom` is created and the `User` is correctly associated with the new `Classroom` but the `Classroom` is not associated to the existing `User`.

```
type User @model {
  id: ID!
  userType: String!
  teacherClassrooms: [Classroom] @connection(name: "TeacherClassrooms")
}

type Classroom @model {
  id: ID!
  teacher: User @connection(name: "TeacherClassrooms")
  linkCode: String!
  name: String!
}
```

---

```
export type CreateClassroomInput = {
  id?: string | null,
  linkCode: string,
  name: string,
  classroomTeacherId?: string | null,
};
```

So, if I query for `listClassrooms`, each classroom comes back with its associated `User`. But if I query for a `User` they do not have any classrooms in their `teacherClassrooms` array.

Do I need to `updateUser` when I create a new `Classroom`? My intuition, and my understanding of [the docs](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/cli-toolchain/graphql#connection), lead me to believe that AppSync would handle both updates when `@connection` is specified on a model property.

Or is this just a way of indicating to the backend that "for each Id in this property array assume it's of type X and when queried go fetch by Id against the corresponding table"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your list query. I had the same issue and then realised that generated list query was missing relation attributes after I updated schema with name connection. In your case something like this

```
listUsers { 
  items { 
    id 
    teacherClassrooms { 
      items { 
        linkCode 
        id name 
      } 
    } 
  } 
}
```

inside your `listUsers` query

Comment: Thanks Marek you were right, I'm still pretty new to graphql. Here is the full call, when you update I'll accept...`  listUsers {
    items {
      id
      teacherClassrooms {
        items {
          linkCode
          id
          name
        }
      }
    }
  }`